# How to reference a value for a key in a hash

Tags: ruby

I want to be able to reference to a key in a `Hash` so that if the value for that key changes, so does anything referencing to it like so

```
hash = {}

hash[1] = "foo"
hash[2] = hash[1]

hash[1] = "bar"

puts hash[2] # I want this to be "bar"
```

Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. Here's what's happening:

```
hash[1] = "foo"   # hash[1] is now a reference to the object "foo".
hash[2] = hash[1] # hash[2] is now a reference to the object "foo" as well,
                  #   since it is what hash[1] is a reference to.
hash[1] = "bar"   # hash[1] is now a reference to the object "bar"
```

Note that assigning `hash[1]` does not change the object it refers to, but rather simply changes the object it references.

In Ruby (like many higher-level languages) you do not have pointers and have no explicit ability to manipulate references.

However, there are some methods that are mutable, on String one such example is `upcase!`. In this example we can see that this method modifies the actual object being referenced without assigning a new object (and thus the references remain unchanged):

```
hash[1] = "foo"   #=> "foo"
hash[2] = hash[1] #=> "foo"
hash[2].upcase!   #=> "FOO"
hash              # => {1=>"FOO", 2=>"FOO"}
```

Comment: @Axsuul No problem! I believe that Python behaves similarly to Ruby in this regard, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you use object wrapper:

```
class A
  attr_accessor :a

  def initialize(a)
    @a = a
  end
end

hash = {}
hash[1] = A.new("before")
hash[2] = hash[1]
hash[1].a = "after"
puts hash[2].a # => "after
```

It's why `upcase!` works -- you don't change reference, but object itself. As far as I remember similar mechanism is used in Rails for passing parameters between controller and view.