# Setting few hash parameters with same value but different keys

Tags: ruby

I have a construction in my application for which I need a hash like this:

`{ 1 => [6,2,2], 2 => [7,4,5], (3..7) => [7,2,1] }`

So I would like to have same value for keys 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7.
Sure above example doesn't work cause Ruby is intelligent and sets hash key as given: it sets range as key :) So I can only access my value as `my_hash[(3..7)]` and `my_hash[3]`, `my_hash[4]` and so on are nil.
Sure I can have a check or construction outside of hash to do what I need, however I am curious if it is possible to set a hash like this without using any loops outside hash declaration? If not, what is most elegant one? Thanks!

Comment: what do you want is not clear? what output you want? what input you have?

Comment: @iAmRubuuu I think it is pretty clear, they are looking for a way to intialize Hashes easily without a loop where they can specify a ranges of keys to have the same values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reference a value for a key in a hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379814/how-to-reference-a-value-for-a-key-in-a-hash)

Comment: Oh, are you looking for the keys to *reference* the same value, or *initialize* as the same value? I may have been too quick with the duplicate vote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there anything especially wrong with this?

```
myhash = { 1 => [6,2,2], 2 => [7,4,5] }
(3..7).each { |k| myhash[k] = [7,2,1] }
```

Comment: Thanks mate! That's the most sexy and that's what I am gonna use :)

Answer (score 5):

You could subclass `Hash` to make it easier to construct such hashes:

```
class RangedHash < Hash
  def []=(key, val)
    if key.is_a? Range
      key.each do |k|
        super k, val
      end
    else
      super key, val
    end
  end
end
```

It works the same as a normal hash, except when you use a Range key, it sets the given value at every point in the Range.

```
irb(main):014:0> h = RangedHash.new
=> {}
irb(main):015:0> h[(1..5)] = 42
=> 42
irb(main):016:0> h[1]
=> 42
irb(main):017:0> h[5]
=> 42
irb(main):018:0> h['hello'] = 24
=> 24
irb(main):019:0> h['hello']
=> 24
```

Comment: Thanks, it's great, I only need this functionality in one place yet, so I won't write a class specially for it ^^ However if I would need it second time (and I bet I would) I would use your implementation :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a way to set multiple keys using literal hash syntax, or without some iteration, but here's a short way to do it with iteration:

```
irb(main):007:0> h = { 1 => [6,2,2], 2 => [7,4,5] }; (3..7).each {|n| h[n] = [7,2,1]}; h
=> {1=>[6, 2, 2], 2=>[7, 4, 5], 3=>[7, 2, 1], 4=>[7, 2, 1], 5=>[7, 2, 1], 6=>[7, 2, 1], 7=>[7, 2, 1]}
```

(Note that the trailing `; h` is just for displaying purposes above.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't like the idea of creating separate key/value pairs for every possible entry in a range. It's not scalable at all, especially for wide ranges. Consider this small range:

```
'a' .. 'zz'
```

which would result in 702 additional keys. Try `('a'..'zz').to_a` for fun. Go ahead. I'll wait.

Instead of creating the keys, intercept the lookup. Reusing the `RangedHash` class name:

```
class RangedHash < Hash
  def [](key)
    return self.fetch(key) if self.key? key

    self.keys.select{ |k| k.is_a? Range }.each do |r_k|
      return self.fetch(r_k) if r_k === key
    end

    nil
  end
end

foo = RangedHash.new
foo[1]    = [6,2,2]
foo[2]    = [7,4,5]
foo[3..7] = [7,2,1]
```

At this point `foo` looks like:

```
{1=>[6, 2, 2], 2=>[7, 4, 5], 3..7=>[7, 2, 1]}
```

Testing the method:

```
require 'pp'
3.upto(7) do |i|
  pp foo[i]
end
```

Which outputs:

```
[7, 2, 1]
[7, 2, 1]
[7, 2, 1]
[7, 2, 1]
[7, 2, 1]
```

For any value in a range this outputs the value associated with that range. Values outside the range, but still defined in the hash, work normally, as does returning `nil` for keys that don't exist in the hash. And, it keeps the hash as small as possible.

The downside to this, or any solution to the question, is the keys that are ranges could overlap, causing collisions. In most of the proposed solutions, the keys would stomp on each other, which would/could end up returning bad values. This method won't do that because it'd take a direct conflict to overwrite a range-key.

To fix this would require deciding whether overlaps are allowed, and, if so, is it OK that the first one found is returned, or should there be logic that determines "best-fit", i.e., the smallest range that fits, or some other criteria entirely. Or, should overlaps be joined to make a larger range if the value is the same? It's a can of worms.

Answer (score 1):

Patching Hash directly, but otherwise the same idea as [Luke's...](https://stackoverflow.com/users/394282/luke)

```
class Hash
  alias_method :orig_assign, '[]='
  def []= k, v
    if k.is_a? Range
      k.each { |i| orig_assign i, v }
      v
    else
      orig_assign k, v
    end
  end
end

t = {}
t[:what] = :ever
t[3..7] = 123
p t # => {5=>123, 6=>123, 7=>123, 3=>123, 4=>123, :what=>:ever}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some more approach:

```
h = { 1 => [6,2,2], 2 => [7,4,5], (3..7) => [7,2,1] } 

def my_hash(h,y)
  h.keys.each do |x|
    if (x.instance_of? Range) and (x.include? y) then
      return p h[x]
    end
  end
p h[y]
end

my_hash(h,2)
my_hash(h,3)
my_hash(h,1)
my_hash(h,10)
my_hash(h,5)
my_hash(h,(3..7))
```

*Output:*

```
[7, 4, 5]
[7, 2, 1]
[6, 2, 2]
nil
[7, 2, 1]
[7, 2, 1]
```

Comment: **Down-voter:** why down vote? explain please. Before down voting SO clearly shown you a message to put your reason. You have no rights to ignore that.

Comment: Down votes cost them, just as they cost you. A lot of people practice drive-by downvoting and are too chicken*&*( to say why they downvote. When I know I have a good answer and get downvoted, such as in my answer, I figure it's because they're too ignorant to understand, so don't worry about it. Just have a higher ratio of good answers to bad and it'll work itself out in the long run.

Comment: @theTinMan you are right! the code I have given,I have tested it. but don't know who down-vote without asking me his/her confusion. This is very poor practice. I am giving you up-vote.

Comment: I have upvote set for each answer including you, so that's definetly not me ^^